# Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains a function in property - firebase

Tags: html, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, datetimepicker

I'm trying to push the values into my firebase-database. When I try pushing the values it gives me an error in the console (Error: Reference.push failed: first argument contains a function in property). I looked it up on firebase and found out it was because of a function being pushed, but i'm not pushing any function at all. But I have a feeling that it might be because of datetimepicker. Need help!

**MY JS**

```
/*global angular*/
var app = angular.module('downtime', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    'use strict';
    $routeProvider.when('/downtime', {
        templateUrl: 'downtime/downtime.html',
        controller: 'downtimeCtrl'
    });
}]);

app.controller('downtimeCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray', function ($scope, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray) {
    'use strict';

     $scope.allEquipments = [];
     $scope.allSystems = [];

    $scope.manageDowntime = function () {

        var doesExist = false;
        angular.forEach ($scope.data , function (d) {
        angular.forEach (d.equipments, function (e) {
        })
    });
        firebase.database().ref('downtime/' + $scope.equipment + '/downtime').push({
            equipment: $scope.equipment,
            type : $scope.type,
            start: $scope.startDT,
            end: $scope.endDT
        });
};

    var ref = firebase.database().ref();
        var data = ref.child("data");
        var list = $firebaseArray(data);

        list.$loaded().then(function(data) {
            $scope.data = data;
            angular.forEach ($scope.data , function (d) {

              $scope.allSystems.push(d.$id);  

                angular.forEach (d.equipments, function (e) {
                    $scope.allEquipments.push(e.equipment);
                    console.log($scope.allEquipments);
                })
            });
            console.log($scope.data);
        }).catch(function(error) {
            $scope.error = error;
        });

    $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
    $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker();

}]);

app.directive('customzdatetime', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datetimepicker({
                debug: false,
                format: 'DD-MM-YYYY hh:mm'
            }).on('dp.change', function (e) {
                ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**My HTML**

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>MANAGE DOWNTIME </h1>
</div>
<div data-ng-app="downtime">

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3" id="equipList">
      <label for="selectequ">Select Equipment</label>
       <select class="form-control" id="selectequ" data-ng-model="equipment" 
          >
        <option data-ng-repeat="eq in allEquipments" >{{eq}}</option>
      </select>

        {{equipment}}
    </div>

        <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xs-offset-3" id="Type">
         <label for="searchType">Search by Type:</label>
         <select class="form-control" id="searchType" data-ng-model="type">
            <option value="" disabled="" selected="" style="display: none">Select type of maintenance</option>
            <option>Corrective Maintenance</option>
            <option>Preventive Maintenance</option>
            <option>Standby</option>
         </select>
      </div>

        {{type}}

    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
      <label for="date">Start of Downtime</label>
<!--        <input type="datetime-local" id="datetimepicker1" class="form-control" placeholder="Day, Month, Year" data-ng-model="startDT"/>-->

                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Day, Month, Year" data-ng-model="startDT" customzdatetime />
    </div>
        {{startDT}}
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3">
      <label for="date">End of Downtime</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Day, Month, Year" data-ng-model="endDT" customzdatetime/>
        {{endDT}}
    </div>



    </div>

<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6" id="central">
            <a class="btn cd-add-to-cart cd-add-to-cart:hover cd-add-to-cart:active" role="button" data-ng-click="manageDowntime()">MANAGE   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

firebase will not accept date as datatype, try to convert them as string or number and then try to push it into the firebase. I hope your problem is the $scope.startDT because it contains some function in it, your're trying to use it directly that is why it throws a error, try to convert them as string or number, then try to push.

```
firebase.database().ref('downtime/' + $scope.equipment + '/downtime').push({
        equipment: $scope.equipment,
        type : $scope.type,
        start: new Date($scope.startDT).toLocaleString(),
        end: new Date($scope.endDT).toLocaleString()
        or
        start: new Date($scope.startDT).getTime(), //this will get you unix timestamp as number
        end: new Date($scope.endDT).getTime()
    });
```